# xml configuration castle windsor

Tags: castle-windsor

I am currently using different installer for different deployment situations:

```
<configSections>
 <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor" />
</configSections>

<castle>
    <installers>
        <install type="Bla.OwinIntegrationTestsControllerInstaller, Bla"/>
    </installers>
    <components>
    </components>
</castle>
```

This gives me more control but is not fine grained enough. So I intend to express my installer's configuration code in xml. Just curious, how do I express this:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
.Pick().If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
.Configure(configurer => configurer.Named(configurer.Implementation.Name))
.LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

in xml?